# right border is missing after apply margin-left

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

My right border is missing after i applied margin-left to the box [(Example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZInJ.png).
There is no problem if i remove margin-left [(Example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/docdH.png).
any way to solve it?

**Css:**

```
position: absolute;
border-color: grey;
border-style: solid;
z-index: 10;
width: 96%;
margin-left: 40px;
height: 52.05rem;
top: 0.3rem;
```

Comment: Try using [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: show your html code

Comment: @Xufox I have tried...does not work

Comment: @McSam Then [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: _“any way to solve it?”_ - depends on what exactly “it” is - you neglected to give us an actual, proper description of what you want to achieve here. Please go read [ask] in that regard. If you just want an absolute positioned box that goes from 40px from the left of the reference system to 0 on the right - well then specify exactly that: `left: 40px; right: 0` and set the width to auto.

Comment: @CBroe thanks! that's what i want...sorry for my bad question..i'm new here

Comment: @Xufox, CBroe it's pretty obvious what was being asked.  Perhaps word your "How to ask" suggestions a bit... friendlier?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Referring the answer from [Ehsan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942534/9944559), I'm manage to solve the problem perfect by adding the following css..

```
width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: Why did you remove the mark for my answer and copy my answer in your post?

Comment: Mc Sam, you shouldn't answer your own question like this. if Eshan's answer helped you, you should mark his as best answer.

Comment: Hi, first of all @Ehsan thanks for your answer...there was a slightly changes in my answer...I remove the mark because I tried to modified your answer same like mine but u removed it...that's why i remove the mark...noted: 96% change to 100%

Comment: @Ehsan can u edit your answer so that i will mark your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`width` of element is bigger than `width` container. So try this:

```
width: calc(96% - 40px);
```